# Delete a row from bootstrap-table when a button is pressed in another column of the same table

Tags: php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uklvh.png)

I want to delete the corresponding row when the delete button is pressed and also remove the row from MySQL database too, so it doesn't render again when I reload the page.
This is the code for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var $table = $('#table');
`$table.bootstrapTable({
    url: 'book-list.php',
    search: true,
    pagination: true,
    buttonsClass: 'primary',
    showFooter: true,
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'num',
            title: '#',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            field: 'first',
            title: 'Book Title',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            field: 'second',
            title: 'Borrower',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            field: 'third',
            title: 'Issue Date',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            field: 'fourth',
            title: 'Action',
            sortable: true,
            formatter: function(value, row, index) {
                return '<button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" data-id="' + row.id + '">Delete</button>';
            },
            events: {
                'click .delete-btn': function(e, value, row, index) {
                    var id = row.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function(data) {
                            $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                                field: 'id',
                                values: [id]
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

</script>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
// establish a connection to the MySQL database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check if the connection was successful
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// get the ID of the row to be deleted from the POST data
$id = $_POST['id'];

// construct and execute the SQL query to delete the row from the database
$sql = "DELETE FROM borrowed_books WHERE id = $id";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    // the row was successfully deleted, send a success response
    echo "success";
} else {
    // there was an error deleting the row, send an error response
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

I tried everything, even taking some help from ChatGPT but this thing doesn't work the way I want it to.
Any kind help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting because the code looks like it would work?

Comment: Well, it doesn't simply work
Can u suggest any changes

Comment: I suggest you look at the error logs in your php script and see if you have any errors there. Also, you should post your php script too.

Comment: Alright, I will add my PHP script too